# Is there free software to bridge Twitter to identi.ca?

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter, identica

I googled it and found some un-free solutions, *[Twitter to Identi.ca Gateway](http://snowulf.com/2010/05/20/twitter-to-identi-ca-gateway/)* and *[Identi.ca to Twitter Bridge](http://thepursuitofalife.com/identica-to-twitter-bridge/)*.

It seems answers were all led to [twitterfeed.com](http://twitterfeed.com/).

I, personally, prefer not to sign up to so many sites, with or without [OpenID](http://OpenID).

So my question is: is there an open source project to build the bridge from Twitter to [identi.ca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identi.ca) so I can upload it to [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine)? A one way bridge would be nice enough. I mean, when I post on Twitter, tweets are automatically synchronized to identi.ca.